# Howto lookup NAPTR records in Go?

Tags: dns, go

I am attempting to query `NAPTR` records in Go. It appears the `DNS` basics provided in the 'net' library won't give me access. I am therefore looking at using ([see docs](https://github.com/miekg/dns)), but can't find any basic examples. Are there any recommendations on alternatives or some insight on how to query for `NAPTR`?

Comment: I would recommend you to file a feature request to implement more parts of DNS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, you would have to roll your own for the net library.  Using [miekg/dns](https://github.com/miekg/dns), I would think something like this:

```
m := new(dns.Msg)
m.SetQuestion("statdns.net.", dns.TypeNAPTR)
ret, err := dns.Exchange(m, "8.8.8.8:53")
```

From the `ret`, you should have an `Answer` member of `[]RR`.  I'm presupposing you can access like:

```
if t, ok := ret.Answer[0].(*dns.NAPTR); ok {
    // do something with t.Order, t.Preference, etc.
}
```

The available members are defined in the [NAPTR type](http://godoc.org/github.com/miekg/dns#NAPTR).

Caveat emptor: I'm away from my workstation for a bit and can't try this out...

Comment: That seemed to do the trick generally, as I get:  2013/12/22 15:41:42 ;; opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 30793
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;statdns,net. IN  NAPTR

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
. 1800 IN SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2013122201 1800 900 604800 86400. Now I just need to see if it works in some other contexts. Thank you.

Comment: Great, glad it worked in general. Please post your final code if relevant for posterity... and hopefully accept this answer. :)

Comment: So, I am getting it to work with [this](https://gist.github.com/jsgoecke/bebeec32061ca82edb9c) with some modifications to protect the innocent. Having said this, parsing the NAPTR and SRV records feels quite manual, having to REGEX to find what I need. Is there a way to load this message results into a struct? Again, not obvious to me looking through the code of the library.

Comment: Off-hand, what about: `naptr, err := dns.NewNAPTR(ret)`.  I know this API pattern works for [RR records](http://godoc.org/github.com/miekg/dns).  Should work, based on the presence of a regex in the [NAPTR struct](http://godoc.org/github.com/miekg/dns#NAPTR)

Comment: `dns.NewNAPTR()` does not exist on the interface. And I have tried a few other things like `naptr, err := new(dns.NAPTR(msg.Answer))` and get type errors, since `msg.Answer` is type `[]dns.RR`, similar issue for just msg. Also looked to see if I could pass in something like `var natpr dns.NAPTR` but nothing on the interface for that either.

Comment: Browsing thru the miekg/dns source (zscan.go), I see the RR lexer for RFC 1035 zones, but nothing for 2915 or 3403 NAPTR.  Can you loop `msg.Answer` into `dns.ReadRR()`?  I'll update my answer with an example.